# old web host doesn't have phpmyadmin, remote access?

Tags: mysql

A new client of mine has a site hosted on netnation (boo).  Their account manager doesn't have a way to access phpmyadmin or anyway to access the database.  I'm not a programer, I'd just like to be able to view a stored password so I can give it to my client.  I have the database host, user, password, and database name in the php files of the site.

Is there a program that I can use to view the database?  No command line please it's not my thing and I'd probably break something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most live databases don't allow direct access from outside the server, so if you're unlucky it can't work unless you can configure mysql to allow access from remote clients, too.

But at least you can try. Just configure any phpmyadmin installation (locally or on another server) to connect to that database. You do that in the file config.inc.php in the phpmyadmin root directory.

Look for the line that says "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';". Just replace 'localhost' with the url or IP your database is running (usually the same as the website). If your mysql allows remote access, you should be good to go. Otherwise you will have to re-configure your mysql installation first to allow that.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is a GUI program that allows access to MySQL database. It can work directly or using SSH. Most likely you won't be able to connect directly so your best chance is to get SSH access and connect using it. If it's not an option you can get FTP access and install phpMyAdmin (simply by uploading it to server).

Also, it's considered a bad practice to store password in DB, so it's very likely that the password itself is not stored, just its hash.